# Number Search (Most efficient)

Tags: java, random, numbers

Given that N is a random number (range 1 to 1000). We need to guess the N and for each guess, one of the following feedbacks may be given:

1. The guess is correct;
2. The guess is too large, so you should guess a smaller number;
3. The guess is too small, so you should guess a larger number.

In case 3, the value of N will increase by P, where P is another random number(range 1 to 200).

If the initial value of N=800 and P=150. You guess in the following sequence:
 [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3FQE.png)

How do you code the following especially when it involves two number (N and P). I was thinking of using Binary Search but the it would be a problem if we do not know the value of P.

This is my code as of now :

```
myGuess=0;
checkCode=0;
int lower = 1, upper = 999;
myGuess = (lower+upper)/2;

do{
    if (checkCode == 2) {
    upper = myGuess - 1;
    }
else if (checkCode == 3){
    lower = myGuess + 1;
    upper += ran.nextInt(200);  //Need to guess the P value
    }

    myGuess = (lower+upper)/2;
}while(checkCode!=1);
```

Comment: `upper += ran.nextInt(200);` This line makes no sense to me. Why do you think you need to alter `upper` here? If your number was too small, you'll update the lower bound and nothing else.

Comment: You should define named constants for `checkCode` rather than using `1`, `2` and `3` directly, whose meaning the reader has to guess.

Comment: I'm not sure P should change whenever your guess is too low. In fact your example suggests that P is initialized with a random value _once_.

Comment: Where is `N` (that is, the number to guess) ever set? Where is the code to set checkCode = 1 (thus actually having guessed the number). Is there ever any indication of what the true upper bound would be after guessing too small (or must one assume that the upper bound actually moves by 200 even though the number to guess moves by 1..200).

Comment: Is the upper bound `1000` (the usual meaning of "1 to 1000") or is it `999` (as your code suggests)?

Comment: @Tom, if the the number guessed is lower than the actual value, we are required to add P to N (N+P). P is a random integer from 1-200. That is the reason I added that to the upper. But still, randomly guessing the P is not that efficient.

Comment: @Holger, sorry for not defining the checkCode. 1 = Same value, 2 = value guessed is bigger than N. 3 = value guessed is smaller than N

Comment: @RichardLuis You're only required to do that if your homework says that you should do that. If it doesn't then doing that doesn't make any sense (and it is error-prone, because adding `P` can move "lower" above the searched number)

Comment: @KevinO, yes. N = number to be guessed. Upper bound = 1000 and lower bound is 1. If the guessed number is lower than N, the upper bound is added with P (a random number from 1-200 which remains constant for each set).

Comment: @Tom, the upper bound which is the max value of N changes if it falls to the condition number 3 (N+P). Look here for a better understanding : https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3FQE.png

Comment: @Holger, this is because when the user guesses a lower number previously. The upper bound is increased (N + P). Hope you get it.

Comment: @Holger: its an [unreliable narrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreliable_narrator) -- just the next step in welcoming our new overlords...

Comment: In that case, you might adapt your binary search to prefer higher guesses instead of the middle of the range, to reduce the likelihood of an increase. But, “the upper bound is increased” is an entirely different statement than “the number to guess has changed”. There is no causal relationship between them, hence you can’t use either to “explain” the other.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to obtain a working guessing system. This code provides a rough guide to a binary search approach. The second step would the be to analyze how to improve efficiency. (note: can restore some of the S.O.P() to see progress)

```
private static int doGuess()
{
    int lowerBound = 1;
    int upperBound = 1000;
    int numberToGuess = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(upperBound) + 1;
    int guess = 0;
    int steps = 0;
    int increases = 0;

    while (guess != numberToGuess) {
        ++steps;

        guess = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;

//            System.out.printf("[%5d] Guessing %d (is: %d)%n",
//                    steps,
//                    guess,
//                    numberToGuess);

        if (guess == numberToGuess) {
            System.out.printf("Guessed %d in %d steps (%d increases)%n",
                    numberToGuess,
                    steps,
                    increases);
            continue;
        }
        else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
//                System.out.println("Guess is too high!");
            // adjust upper bound to be guess
            upperBound = guess;
        }
        else {
//                System.out.println("Guess is too low; changing number");
            numberToGuess += ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(200) + 1;

            // adjust lower bound to this guess
            lowerBound = guess;

            // the number moved, so adjust upper bound by max range
            upperBound += 200;

            // track increases
            ++increases;
        }
    }

    return steps;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Integer> steps = new ArrayList<>();
    int iterations = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        steps.add(doGuess());
    }

    IntSummaryStatistics stats = 
            steps.stream().collect(IntSummaryStatistics::new,
                    IntSummaryStatistics::accept,
                    IntSummaryStatistics::combine);

    System.out.println(stats);
}
```

Output:

```
Guessed 8838 in 145 steps (83 increases)
Guessed 6301 in 106 steps (59 increases)
Guessed 3239 in 58 steps (30 increases)
Guessed 5785 in 109 steps (58 increases)
Guessed 2547 in 56 steps (27 increases)
Guessed 16071 in 300 steps (164 increases)
Guessed 3847 in 54 steps (31 increases)
Guessed 3125 in 42 steps (24 increases)
Guessed 6708 in 93 steps (57 increases)
Guessed 7433 in 143 steps (74 increases)
IntSummaryStatistics{count=10, sum=1106, min=42, average=110.600000, max=300}
```

[Note: based upon quick simulations, the average across multiple runs is about 115, so efficiency improvements should reduce on average from 115 steps]
[Note: the amount of change in the code is different with each guess that is too low; a comment by the OP might suggest the increase is randomly chosen once, in which case the increase in the number to guess in the above code would need to change]

**Edit:**
Logically if guessing low moves the the number one is to guess, then using some sort of bias towards picking higher would seem to be logical. As Holger has suggest in the various comments, there are some ways to make adjustments.

I had attempted some basic adjustments prior to seeing Holger's suggestion; I then also attempted to implement his algorithm. However, I have not found the adjustments to make a marked improvement (and some are worse).

Using 100,000 runs, the standard binary search averaged 127.7 steps (note: up slightly from my earlier estimate based upon a lower run count). Assuming I implemented Holger's algorithm correctly, at 100,000 the average was 126.6 steps.

As I lack the math skills (and unfortunately time at the moment) to investigate further, it seems that simple modifications do not seem to radically change the efficiency of the algorithm *on average*. I did not investigate worse cases. It would be interesting to ask the question over on the Math StackExchange to see if they could provide any definite input. I did do a quick Google search, but did not have time to read the academic papers that might give some improvement (again, with unknown trade-offs in speed and algorithmic complexity).

It is, of course, possible I did not implement Holgen's suggestion properly. Here is the code I used (replacing the change in the guess calculation if too low) based straight from the comment:

```
              if (tryHolgen) {
                double risc = 200.0/(upperBound-lowerBound);
                if (risc <= 1) {
                    guess = (upperBound + lowerBound) /2;
                }
                else {
                    guess = upperBound - 
                      Math.max((int)((upperBound - lowerBound)/risc/2),1);
                }
              else {
                guess = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
            }
```

I am curious if others have a better implementation than the straight binary search.

It is interesting, though, that a 1..1000 range with a standard binary search would take 8 steps on average with O(log *n*) complexity. By allowing the guess to change, it moves the average by about 120 steps.

Comment: This is my first time on stackoverflow and WOW! I'm actually mind blown on how fast everybody answers the question especially with coding and output. What are you guys? A robot. Hahah. #lotsofrespect

Comment: Tested your code implementation and it works as intended. My previous code (average step : 150) somehow worked the same as yours but yours seem to take less steps to guess the number. Looking forward for a more efficient (faster steps) to guess the number. Thanks

Comment: @Richard Luis: as said in my previous comment, you can be more efficient by not using the middle as guess, but prefer higher values to reduce the likelihood of an increase operation. You might balance the potential gain (halving the search range) to the potential loss (increasing it by up to `200`, or `100` on average). So you could calculate the `double risc = 200.0/(upperBound-lowerBound);` and use `guess = risc<=1? (upperBound+lowerBound)/2: upperBound-Math.max((int)((upperBound-lowerBound)/risc/2),1);` which will prefer higher numbers for smaller search ranges, to accommodate the risk.

Comment: @Holger, thanks for your suggestion. I will give it a try and keep you updated. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I reworked my solution once I understood what you were trying to do. This will give you some statistics. The current solution incorporates a random number between 0 and 13 for each guess, as well as adding the lower and upper bound together and divide them by 2. Why 13? It seems like it's a sweet spot for this exact task.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    int numTests = 1000000;
    long averageTries = 0;
    int maxAttempts = 0;
    int minAttempts = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++) {
        int numAttempts = 0;
        int answer = (int) (Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
        int lower = 1;
        int upper = 1000;
        int myGuess;

        do {
            myGuess = (int) (((lower + upper) / 2) + (Math.random() * 14));
            numAttempts++;

            if (myGuess > answer) {
                upper = myGuess;
            } else if (myGuess < answer) {
                lower = myGuess;
                upper += (lower + upper) / 2;
                answer += (int) (Math.random() * 200) + 1;
            }

        } while (myGuess != answer);
        averageTries += numAttempts;

        if (numAttempts > maxAttempts) {
            maxAttempts = numAttempts;
        }
        if (numAttempts < minAttempts) {
            minAttempts = numAttempts;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Average attempts (of " + numTests + " tests): " + (averageTries / numTests));
    System.out.println("Most attempts in one run: " + maxAttempts);
    System.out.println("Least attempts in one run: " + minAttempts);
}
```

Output:

```
Average attempts (of 1000000 tests): 266
Most attempts in one run: 72228
Least attempts in one run: 1
```

Comment: While this answer does provide the implementation of a binary search and addresses the missing details in the OP's poor code example, it doesn't answer the question of efficiency.

Comment: What sense does it make to include the answer when updating the bounds? The bounds are set according to your guesses and nothing else.

Comment: @Tom It doesn't - I thought it would be needed at first, but it's completely fine without.

Comment: @AlgorithmR, thanks for your code implementation. Gonna give it a try and will update you if it works.

Comment: @AlgorithmR, the variable N cannot be set or get. In your code implementation you somehow used the "answer += (lower + upper) / 2"

Comment: @RichardLuis, I've re-written some of the code now that I've gotten a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlgorithmR, thanks, this is what I coded similarly. Unfortunately, the average attempts are too high in this case. I'm trying to achieve a more efficient way to bring down the average attempts below 100.

Comment: @RichardLuis, I've managed to bring it down to ~260 on average, but that's still way above your league! Good luck with the task! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something similar to binary search. Just consider that binary search requires the input to be sorted. If the input is not sorted you have to sort it yourself.

Rather than guessing a random number, just guess the one exactly in the middle of the partition. However compared with binary search which halves each time, in this case it's a moving target, so the bounds of the search need to be adjusted for that.